# Magento add newsletter subscribe in checkout

Tags: magento, newsletter

I want to make it possible that a new customer should sign up to the newsletter while the checkout process (if he create a new account).

So I have put a `checkbox` in the `billing.phtml` file as follow:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" 
      title="newsletter_signup" value="1"  class="checkbox"/>
<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter 2') ?>
```

But nothing has happened. It did not work. I think I must do more? But I don't know what?

Comment: I'm sure the name needs to be `billing[is_subscribed]`, what version of Magento are you running?

Comment: wich name do you mean? Magento 1.9.1

Comment: The name of the input.

Comment: ok, i have change the name but it wont work -  Have i include the xml or observer file in another existing file? How the files will call up from the billing.phtml?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the process you can follow -

add below code at billing.phtml

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1"  checked="checked" class="checkbox" />
```

using the event **checkout_submit_all_after** subscribe the customer to newsletter

```
<global>
 <events>
    <checkout_submit_all_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_submit_all_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento52274/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>AssignNewletter</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
  </global>
```

And Observer code is :

```
public function AssignNewletter($observer) {
            $event = $observer->getEvent();
            $order = $event->getOrder();
        $Quote =$event->getQuote();
        if (in_array($Quote()->getCheckoutMethod(), array('register','customer'))):

        if Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed')){
        $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($Quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail());
        }
        endif;
   }
```

**Full Module:**

**Step1:** create config.xml at app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento52274/etc/ and code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento52274>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento52274>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento52274>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento52274_Model</class>
      </magento52274>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_submit_all_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_submit_all_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento52274/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>AssignNewletter</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Step2:** create Observer.php at app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento52274/Model/ and code is

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento52274_Model_Observer
{

    public function AssignNewletter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
            $order = $event->getOrder();
        $Quote =$event->getQuote();
        if (in_array($Quote()->getCheckoutMethod(), array('register','customer'))):

            if Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)){
        $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($Quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail());
         }
        endif;
    }

}
```

**Step3:** create Module  app/etc/modules/Stackexchange_Magento52274.xml and code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento52274>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento52274>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**Step4:** And also need add newsletter field at billing.phtml a

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1"  checked="checked" class="checkbox" />
```

Comment: I have done the steps like you told, but it wont work.

Have i include the xml or observer file in another existing file? How the files will call up from the billing.phtml?

Comment: Are you reaching to the observer ? Please check once and let me know.

Comment: I think that is the problem - how can i check it - or how will be reach the observer file. In the billing.phml is no "link" to the observer oder other xml file - so i dont understand how it should work...

Comment: if (in_array($Quote->getCheckoutMethod(), array('register','customer'))):
Above is correct statement